# Prevent Redis from saving to disc

Tags: redis, bulkinsert

I'm building a Redis db which consumes nearly all of my machines memory. If Redis startes to save to disc while heavy inserting is going on, the memory consumption is more or less doubled (as described in the documentation). This leads to terrible performance in my case.

I would like to force Redis to not to store any data while I'm inserting and would trigger the save manually afterwards. That should solve my problem, but however I configure the "save" setting, at some point in time Redis starts to save to disc. Any hint how to prevent Redis from doing so?

Comment: Interesting. I don't have the right answer for you but maybe you could run Redis in RDB mode and make it save the data hourly (minutely, daily or other interval). Then if you can controll the inserts you would stop the inserts before redis is about to save to disk. Just an idea. :)

Comment: It's running in RDB mode and I set it to write to disc every 100 hours or so. But it starts earlier. Pausing the insert process would introduce way to much and to fragile workaround logic.

Comment: How about instead of pausing using a queue instead of writing directly to redis? I know both of the solutions I suggested aren't that good, but I haven't heard of any "write when I want" policies for redis so far... :/

Comment: One way of easing the memory requirements is to run n instances of redis, and shard the data among the instances. It might turn bad the in the same way if you write a lot to every shard, but odds are they won't all have to write at the same time.

Comment: Did you try removing all the `save` commands from your redis.conf? The documentation says "Note: you can disable saving at all commenting all the "save" lines"

Comment: But how would he then save the data? Can you save you trigger save manually?

Comment: You can trigger a save operation in background by using the bgsave command.

Comment: @SripathiKrishnan: Could you write your comment as an answer which I would accept? That solved my problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can disable saving by commenting all the "save" lines" in your redis.conf.

Answer (score 1):

Alternately, if you don't want to edit any `.conf` files, run Redis with:

`redis-server --save ""`

As per [example config](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/antirez/redis/3.0/redis.conf) (search for `save`):

```
It is also possible to remove all the previously configured save
points by adding a save directive with a single empty string argument
like in the following example:

save ""
```

Answer (score 0):

I would also suggest looking at Persistence only slaves (Master / Slave replication) (Have the slaves persist data instead of master)

Take a look at this [LINK](http://dev.paperlesspost.com/blog/2011/12/21/redis-tips-persistence-only-slaves-and-the-slowlog/)